# Creating JHipster blueprint to extend the field type prompt

Tags: jhipster

I have already created a test blueprint that works, so I kinda got the idea, but I would like to make sure that I am approaching this correctly.

I want to extend the field type prompt to offer custom types alongside String, int, boolean etc.

This means I need to modify the templates, like templates/src/main/java/package/domain/Entity.java.ejs

My blueprint only had generators/client and generators/entity-client, so I guess I have to:

- create generators/entity-server
- create index.js
- create files.js (can I copy that from here https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/generators/entity-server/files.js ?)
- create the templates in entity-server/templates
- create generators/entity
- copy and modify generators/entity/prompts.js: do I have to just write a new prompts.js, or do I have to copy over everything in generators/entity and only change what I would like to change ?

For the templates, can I copy them from the JHipster repo ?
Should I ? If not, why not and what is the alternative ?

If copying them is the right move, do I have to copy everything ? Or just the ones I want to modify ? (I haven't checked yet if I will need to modify everything)

When JHipster is updated, I suppose either I manually merge the new files, or I risk that slowly my code will differ more and more from the JHipster code ?

Is there a simpler method to achieve what I am trying to do ?
It would be nice if I could just say I want to add TypeX and TypeY to that prompt and provide limited templates that only cover those types, like a template for the import, one for the field, and one for the setter and getter, and if only the import is provided, a generic template is used.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer to all your questions.
First to create Blueprint I suggest to use https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster-blueprint even in another folder and copy all you need for your current project. I think it's easier and you could choose which generator you want to add e.g. entity-server and entity.

**Prompts phase**

If you want to modify prompt phase you can merge your phase with the JHipster one like that

```
get prompting() {
        const phaseFromJHipster = super._prompting();
        const phaseFromMe = {
            askForTheme: prompts.askForTheme,
            setMySharedConfigOptions() {
                this.configOptions.theme = this.theme;
            }
        };

        return { ...phaseFromJHipster, ...phaseFromMe };
    }
```

(source: https://github.com/avdev4j/samSuffit/tree/master/generators/client)

But by doing this you can't modify existing questions, for this case you should copy all existing questions into your blueprint.

**Templates management**

Your blueprint is linked with a JHipster version. As I used to say (in my talks) is that you should copy and modify templates from JHipster except for configuration files because it's a bit tricky to handle. For them, I prefer to use JHipster API like 'replaceContent()' or the needle API which allowed you to insert some code into some files (like a dependency in the pom.xml file).
Of course you can use the way you want, but with experiences I prefer to control my templates and merge them when I upgrade the JHipster version.

You should only copy the templates you want to modify, merge JHipster and your writing phase. JHipster use yeoman, which use memfs to handle file generation. Every files are created in memory and dumped at the final step. You can easily override a file without performance compromise.

```
    get writing() {
        const phaseFromJHipster = super._writing();
        /* eslint-disable */
        const phaseFromSam = {
            writeSamFiles() {
                if (this.clientFramework === 'angularX') {
                    return writeAngularFiles.call(this);
                }
            }
        };
        /* eslint-enable */

        return { ...phaseFromJHipster, ...phaseFromSam };
    }
```

**JHipster upgrade**

I suggest you to check templates when upgrading JHipster and apply modifications if needed. Otherwise, you could have bugs. Also, I suggest to set a definitive (like 6.1.0) version of JHipster in your blueprint package.json.

As far I know there is no way to do what you want to do. I'm thinking of a way to modify prompts easily without copying all other questions, if you want to contribute ;).

You can check my blueprint sample I use to show in my talks:
https://github.com/avdev4j/samSuffit/

I hope It can help you can, feel free to ask more.

regards,

Comment: So I added this in my existing blueprint (that was working): generators/entity/prompts.js, and in there under the BLOB I added {
                    value: 'customType',
                    name: 'Custom Type'
                }, but when adding a field to an entity I don't see the option for customType.